# How to show only next post pagination link using wp_link_pages()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to return only next post page links in my wordpress website.
Here is my implementation

```
<?php
   wp_link_pages( array(
    'next_or_number' => 'next',
    'nextpagelink' => 'next',
    'previouspagelink' => false,
    'before' => '<div class="page_links">',
    'after'  => '</div>'
  ) );
?>
```

Output by this piece of code

```
<div class="page_links">
  <a href="http://localhost/circorunning/?p=542&amp;page=2">next</a>
</div>
```

It's fine when It's on the first instance of the page but as soon as I click next , I am getting this output by html.

```
<div class="page_links">
   <a href="http://localhost/circorunning/?p=542"></a> 
   <a href="http://localhost/circorunning/?p=542&amp;page=3">next</a>
</div>
```

but I want only one link, there should be no link to the main post.

```
<div class="page_links"> 
   <a href="http://localhost/circorunning/?p=542&amp;page=3">next</a>
</div>
```

And I do want to use this outside of the loop.